# Why does the makefile insist on compiling things it should not?

Tags: c, makefile

So I run `make lex` and it generates me the `lex.yy.c` file, all good

then I run `make scanner`, which takes a sourcefile called `scanner.c` into compilation, it should simply run `cc lex.yy.c scanner.c -o scanner`, but instead it does this:

```
lex  -t scanner.l > scanner.c
cc lex.yy.c scanner.c -o scanner
```

Why does it decide to run `lex  -t scanner.l` and output it to `scanner.c` effectively overwritting my code? No damned idea, and it's driving me crazy.

my makefile:

```
scanner: scanner.h scanner.c lex.yy.c
    cc lex.yy.c scanner.c -o scanner 

lex: scanner.l
    lex scanner.l > lex.yy.c

clean:
    rm lex.yy.c
    rm scanner
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does it decide to run lex  -t scanner.l and output it to scanner.c effectively overwritting my code?

Whenever this happens you have in your build directory a `scanner.c` and
a `scanner.l` that is more recent than than the `scanner.c`

When you run `make scanner`, the recipe:

```
scanner: scanner.h scanner.c lex.yy.c
    cc lex.yy.c scanner.c -o scanner
```

requires that its prerequisite `scanner.c` shall be made uptodate. You
have provided no recipe that does that, so make falls back
on its database of builtin recipes.

Examine those builtin recipes by running `make -p` and you'll find:

```
%.c: %.l
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    @$(RM) $@ 
     $(LEX.l) $< > $@
```

This builtin recipe will make a `file.c` from the matching `file.l` by running:

```
rm file.c   # Not echoed
lex  -t file.l > file.c
```

Make finds that the pattern rule for this recipe - `%.c: %.l` - is satisfied
by `scanner.c`, because `scanner.l` exists and more recent that than `scanner.c`.
So it uses this recipe to make `scanner.c` uptodate:

```
lex  -t scanner.l > scanner.c
```

thereby clobbering your `scanner.c`.

If you do not want make ever to apply this builtin recipe, you can explicitly
cancel it by writing just the rule:

```
%.c: %.l
```

in your makefile without any recipe.

You can also disable *all* builtin recipes by passing `--no-builtin-rules` on the
make commandline.

*However*, whenever your expectations about the behaviour of a makefile
are sabotaged by the builtin recipes it is strong indication that your expectations
are not well-informed as to the usual way of making output files from input files
with the tools that your makefile invokes. 
Make's [Catalogue of Built-In Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html):

```
%.<target-type>: %.<prereq-type>
    <command>
    ...
```

embody the *canonical way* of making a `<target-type>` file from a `<prereq-type>`
file with make, so that you don't have to keep writing this recipe yourself in
your makefiles. For example C and C++ programmers who are competent with GNU make
do not write recipes to make `.o` files from `.c` files or `.cpp` files, except in
corner cases, because they are know that the way make will do it automatically
is normally the way they want.

Make's builtin recipe for the `%.c: %.l` rule expresses the canonical way of
making `file.c` given a `file.l`. So ask yourself: If you *don't* want `scanner.c`
to be made like that from `scanner.l`, and if instead you want `lex.yy.c` to
be made from `scanner.l`, is it necessary or useful for the file you have called
`scanner.l` to be called that, when you also have a quite independent source file
called `scanner.c`?

Suppose you took advantage of make's builtin recipes as in this toy example:

**lexer.l**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
%%
[ \t] ;
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ { printf("Found a floating-point number: [%s]\n",yytext); }
[0-9]+  { printf("Found an integer: [%s]\n",yytext); }
[a-zA-Z0-9]+ { printf("Found a string: [%s]\n",yytext); }
%%
```

**scanner.c**

```
#include "scanner.h"

int main(void) {
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

**scanner.h**

```
#ifndef SCANNER_H
#define SCANNER_H

extern int yylex(void);

#endif
```

Then your makefile could be just:

**Makefile**

```
SRCS := scanner.c lexer.c
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
LDLIBS := -lfl

.PHONY: all clean

all: scanner

scanner: $(OBJS)
    $(LINK.o) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

scanner.o: scanner.h

clean:
    rm -f scanner *.o
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
cc    -c -o scanner.o scanner.c
lex  -t lexer.l > lexer.c
cc    -c -o lexer.o lexer.c
cc   -o scanner scanner.o lexer.o -lfl
rm lexer.c
```

Note that make runs all these commands:

```
    cc    -c -o scanner.o scanner.c
    lex  -t lexer.l > lexer.c
    cc    -c -o lexer.o lexer.c
```

to make `lexer.c`, `lexer.o` and `scanner.o` without you having
written any recipes that tell it how to do so. It also automatically
notices that `lexer.c` is an *intermediate file* - a generated file that
only needs to exist to get from `lexer.l` to `lexer.o` - so it deletes
it at the end:

```
rm lexer.c
```

without being told to.

And this scanner runs like:

```
$ ./scanner 
hello
Found a string: [hello]

42
Found an integer: [42]

42.42
Found a floating-point number: [42.42]

^C
```

Answer (score 5):

The `make` you are using most certainly defines default suffixes, defining implicit rules which conflicts with the ones you define.

See for instance this [howto](http://www.owen.sj.ca.us/~rk/howto/slides/make/slides/makesuff.html), which explains suffix rules.

At the beginning of your makefiles, you can add a line:

```
.SUFFIXES:
```

to tell `make` you don't want default suffix rules.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have created the following dependency, which doesn't create the named target, and so **is called always, to try to create it**

```
lex: scanner.l           <-- incorrect target name, not created from source.
    lex scanner.l > lex.yy.c
```

This dependency tries to create a file named `lex`, but none is created from the command line below.  Perhaps you wanted this, instead

```
lex.yy.c: scanner.l
    lex scanner.l -olex.yy.c
```

or even

```
lex.yy.c: scanner.l
    lex scanner.l -o$@
```

(use `-o` option, as `lex(1)` doesn't produce the scanner on standard output.  By the way I think, but not sure, lex requires the option argument to be directly in contact to the option `-o`, see the man page)

## NOTE 1

You have a default rule to create a `.c` file from a `.l` file of the same basename.  The rule is something like

```
.l.c:
    $(LEX) $(LFLAGS) -o$@ $<
```

that executes the command in variable `LEX` with flags indicated in `LFLAGS` variable, generating the source C file from a lex input of the same name, but with `.l` extension.